# python columns to one cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I merge the several columns into one cell?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df = df.append(df.agg(['mean', 'std']))
```

I can get the dataframe

```
             A         B
0     1.000000  2.000000
1     1.000000  3.000000
2     4.000000  6.000000
mean  2.000000  3.666667
std   1.732051  2.081666
```

then, I want to covert parts of df to one cell, which I expect is:

```
          A     A_mean    A_std     B           B_mean    B_std   
0     1,1,4     2.0       1.732052  2,3,6     3.666667  2.081666
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the use case for doing this but , you can reshape and concat , similar to below:

```
m = df.agg(['mean', 'std']).unstack().to_frame().T
m.columns = m.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
out = df.astype(str).agg(','.join).to_frame().T.assign(**m).sort_index(axis=1)
```

---

```
print(out)

       A  A_mean     A_std      B    B_mean     B_std
0  1,1,4     2.0  1.732051  2,3,6  3.666667  2.081666
```